# How to 4-way match a subset string columns from separate sheets in Excel (Google Sheets, Python, R answers work, too)

Tags: python, r, excel, google-sheets

**Overview :**
I have lists of urls in multiple sheets, each sheet is a different website domain. I would like to match the equivalent urls for a project to compare webpages from competitor domains to my domain. Additionally, I only want to look at a subset of the most important urls from my domain matched. I already have the slug from my domain matched to each competitor domain url individually in different sheets. I want a subset of this data matched 4-way across all of them. I guess it involves some combination of vlookup and matching functions.

**The Data :**
I will use a dummy-data example for this question. All sheets are on the same spreadsheet excel doc.

**Before:**

```
|---------------------------------------------|
|                  *Sheet 1*                  |
|--------------------------|------------------|
|      URL A               |  My Domain Slug  |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.dogs.com/food        | /dog-food        |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.dogs.com/chew-toys   | /chewtoys        |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.dogs.com/tennis-balls| /tennisballs     |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.dogs.com/dog-beds    | /beds            |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.dogs.com/squeaky-toys| /squeakers       |
|--------------------------|------------------|

|---------------------------------------------|
|                  *Sheet 2*                  |
|--------------------------|------------------|
|      URL B               |  My Domain Slug  |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.canines.com/dogfood  | /dog-food        |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.canines.com/chewies  | /chewtoys        |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.canines.com/balls    | /tennisballs     |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.canines.com/dogbeds  | /beds            |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.canines.com/squeaks  | /squeakers       |
|--------------------------|------------------|

|---------------------------------------------|
|                  *Sheet 3*                  |
|--------------------------|------------------|
|      URL C               |  My Domain Slug  |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.puppies.com/eat      | /dog-food        |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.puppies.com/chew     | /chewtoys        |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.puppies.com/fetch    | /tennisballs     |
|--------------------------|------------------|
|www.puppies.com/sleep     | /beds            |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| www.puppies.com/squeak   | /squeakers       |
|--------------------------|------------------|

|--------------------------------------|
|  *Sheet 4 My Domain Subset*          |
|--------------------------------------|
|   www.mydomain.com/dog-food          |
|--------------------------------------|
|   www.mydomain.com/chewtoys          |
|--------------------------------------|
|   www.mydomain.com/beds              |
|--------------------------------------|
```

**End Goal:**
A subset of my domain, matched across sheets A,B,and C. I already have the subset.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                               *Final Sheet*                                                      |                                                                
|--------------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
|      My Domain (subset)  |      URL A            |      URL B            |      URL C            |
|--------------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| www.mydomain.com/dog-food|  www.dogs.com/food    |www.canines.com/dogfood|www.puppies.com/dogfood|
|--------------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| www.mydomain.com/chewtoys| www.dogs.com/chew-toys|www.canines.com/chewies| www.puppies.com/chews |    
|--------------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| www.mydomain.com/beds    | www.dogs.com/dog-beds |www.canines.com/dogbeds|www.puppies.com/dogmats|
|--------------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
```

**Solution**
I'm working on this in Excel right now, but I can move it to Google Sheets or if anyone has an idea of how to do it in Python or R, I can import the sheets as csv files.

I've tried vlookups, but i suspect I need a match function here too

Comment: So do you already have your domain subset sorted or do you also need to find these (from your example this being the columns ```My domain```)? And if so do you just need to find in the other sheets those URLs that match your domain subset parameters ```dog-food``` ,  ```chewtoys``` and ```beds```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` you need to first extract the slug from the url then join all the sheets on the slug :

```r
library(tidyverse)

sheet.d %>% mutate(My.Domain.Slug=str_extract(URL, "/.+")) -> sheet.d
sheet.d %>% inner_join(sheet.a) %>%  inner_join(sheet.b) %>%  inner_join(sheet.c) %>% select(!My.Domain.Slug)
```

```r
                        URL                  URL.A                   URL.B                 URL.C
1 www.mydomain.com/dog-food      www.dogs.com/food www.canines.com/dogfood   www.puppies.com/eat
2 www.mydomain.com/chewtoys www.dogs.com/chew-toys www.canines.com/chewies  www.puppies.com/chew
3     www.mydomain.com/beds  www.dogs.com/dog-beds www.canines.com/dogbeds www.puppies.com/sleep
```

## Data

```r
read.csv(text="URL A,My Domain Slug
www.dogs.com/food,/dog-food
www.dogs.com/chew-toys,/chewtoys
www.dogs.com/tennis-balls,/tennisballs
www.dogs.com/dog-beds,/beds
www.dogs.com/squeaky-toys,/squeakers")-> sheet.a
read.csv(text="URL B,My Domain Slug
www.canines.com/dogfood,/dog-food
www.canines.com/chewies,/chewtoys
www.canines.com/balls,/tennisballs
www.canines.com/dogbeds,/beds
www.canines.com/squeaks,/squeakers") -> sheet.b
read.csv(text="URL C,My Domain Slug
www.puppies.com/eat,/dog-food
www.puppies.com/chew,/chewtoys
www.puppies.com/fetch,/tennisballs
www.puppies.com/sleep,/beds
www.puppies.com/squeak,/squeakers") -> sheet.c
read.csv(text="URL
www.mydomain.com/dog-food
www.mydomain.com/chewtoys
www.mydomain.com/beds") -> sheet.d
```

Comment: I am getting Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'My.Domain.Slug' not found.....so the actual data has some variations in the urls, like one might not have a corresponding URL. Could this be causing the problem? how should i handle it? Thanks!

Comment: the problem is caused by your data not having `My Domain Slug` as a column, can you make sure all of them have the column. if not post an MWE that actually represents the data

Comment: *palm to face* of course. Ok, inner_join worked out, now!